# doctrine get last message

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this schema in database and how to get last messages and field is_seen is false not true for receiver 10 for example ..
schema database:

[image]

i created this query but I have first message of receiver 10:

query:

```
public function messagesByReceiver($user) {

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\Query */
   $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
      ->select('a')
      ->where('a.receiver = :user')
      ->setParameter('user', $user)
      ->groupBy('a.sender')
      ->orderBy('a.createdAt','DESC')
    ;


   return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, so if I understand you correct you want to use following conditions:

1. receiver_id is 10
2. is_seen is false

And if that is the use case then

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->select('a')
    ->where('a.receiver = :user')
    ->andWhere('a.is_seen = 0')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->groupBy('a.sender')
    ->orderBy('a.createdAt','DESC');
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: i khnow this but my goal is display mailbox of liste user sende message to user 10 ... for example messanger facebook display list users send message to me and where i unread message name of message is colored

Comment: sorry really don't understand what you're trying to do - please explain it - eg. tell us which rows you want from that list to be in your results.